# Use the design function of Qt Creator when developing Ubuntu apps

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qml, click-packages

I would like to start developing Ubuntu apps with Qt Creator and I have a few queries when making a simple qml qt app.

Firstly, is it normal qml and javascript? Can I use all normal qml and javascript code that I would use in QT Creator for ubuntu apps?

Also, can I use the design tab of QT Creator to design the UI of an Ubuntu app? At the moment I get an error 'Errors while reading typeinfo files:', is there a problem with my install or can I not use design with an Ubuntu app with simple UI?

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late but yes you can use most normal QML.You should read the ubuntu api documentation for that.